# Fetching number from JSON decoded code error

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I have the following JSON code:

```
"events":[[457270,70,1,2,[31,"P"],{"0":["S","0","0"],"1":["F","4","2"],"2":["P","0","0"]}...
```

I want to fetch the result from:

```
"1":["F","4","2"]
```

what I have is an foreach statement like this:

```
foreach($array->events as $key=>$val){  
foreach($val->1 as $team) {
        }

    }
```

I want to fetch the values 4 and 2. Can someone help me?
The statement foreach($val->1...) is not allowed. (The number 1 throws error).

Comment: What does `var_dump($array);` show?

Comment: var_dump shows:  ["1"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(16) "F" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "0" }

Answer (score 0):

```
    $decoded = json_decode($events,TRUE);
    var_dump($decoded);
```

You get the json response as an associative array now. You can see the output in var_dump, and you can select the necessary data as per the need.

Answer (score 0):

From your `var_dump`, it appears that it's an array, not an object, so try

```
foreach($val["1"] as $team) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: sorry, no luck with this solution. Based on the code provided here, what echo statement would you use to echo out the value "4" from the code I provided above?

Comment: I actually get the following error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in ...